# Average of values in columns in dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I want to find the mean across a dataframe of values. For example, if I have the following data:

```
ID Value Status
1   10     A
2   15     B
3   20     A
```

And I want to find the mean of all values with the status A in it. How would I do so?

Here is my attempt:

```
dataframe$balance.mean(dataframe$status == 'A')
```

But I keep getting an error that says `Error: attempt to apply non-function`. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understood your requirement clearly, following should meet your requirement:

```
 id<-c(1,2,3)
 val<-c(10,15,20)
 sta<-c("A","B","A")

 df<-data.frame(id,val,sta)

 mean(df$val[df$sta=="A"])
```

Comment: +1, using `with` makes it clearer in theses cases without too many `$`s: `with(df, mean(val[sta=="A"]))`

Comment: and even more readable (arguable) can be: `with(subset(df, sta == "A"), mean(val))`

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `()` is used for function calls, `[]` are used for subsetting. Your are now calling a function while there is actually no function, giving the error message you see.

In a more general sense, for these kinds of things I like to use `plyr`, although `data.table` is an awesome other option.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dataframe, .(Status), summarize, mean_value = mean(Value))
```

This will yield you a new `data.frame` with the average values of `Value` for each unique value of `Status`.

Answer (score 3):

As @PaulHiemstra alluded to, there is a clean `data.table` solution which would be:

```
library(data.table)
DT[Status=="A", mean(val)]
```

where `DT <- as.data.table(your_data_frame)`

---

or you can set the key for quicker results:

```
setkey(DT, "status")
# this will produce a data.table, not a single 
DT["A", mean(val)]
# This produces a single number
DT["A"] [, mean(val)]
```